# I can not seem to clear a string I use to temporarily hold blocks of text

Tags: c

My program is suppose to take strings and print each on a separate line.  I am looking for spaces to decide when to print a word to a new line.  I use a string called hold to store each letter until a space is located.  That word is then printed to the screen.  The problem I have is if the last word in hold was longer than the previous then the new word will be printed with the trailing end of the last word.

example:  if the last word was "Program" and the next word is "cat" the output to the screen will be Program followed by catgram.

below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


char *string;
char *hold;


int main(void)
{
    string = malloc(200);
hold = malloc(50);
int i=0;
int j=0;

printf("please enter a string\n");
scanf("%[^\n]",string);

while (string[i] !='\o')
{
    if (string[i] !=' ')
    {
        hold[j] = string[i];
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n",hold);
        j = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
return 0;
free(string);       
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've misspelled `\0` as `\o`. Edit: oh, you also never terminate the string`hold`.

Comment: Seeing how your problem is solved, can you please accept one of the answers?

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  It is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  so as to properly prototype the functions `free()` and `malloc()`

Comment: when the `return 0;` statement is executed, any following statements, like: `free(string);` will never be executed.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1):

Please add the lines

```
hold[j]='\0';
```

Reason: The end of the string is '\0' if you have not explicitly adding a '\0' it will take the entire string until it finds the first '\0'
and

```
printf("%s\n",hold);
```

Reason: To get the last word printed, if the string of words is not ending with a space

as in the below edited program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *string;
char *hold;


int main(void)  
{
   string = malloc(200);
   hold = malloc(50);
   int i=0;
   int j=0;

   printf("please enter a string\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]",string);
   printf("%s\n",string);

   while (string[i] !='\0')
   {
      if (string[i] !=' ')
      {
          hold[j] = string[i];
          j++;
      }
      else
      {
         hold[j]='\0';         **//Edited here**
         printf("%s\n",hold);
         j = 0;
      }
  i++;
}
printf("%s\n",hold); **//Edited here**
return 0;
free(string);       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This is my first semester in C programming at University.

Answer (score 0):

Strings ended at "\0" not at "\o"

Answer (score 0):

See the thing is, `printf()` prints all the characters in series, until it sees a null byte. Your previous word already filled up some bytes, and since you can read them, obviously, they are not null.

To fix your code, you have to add a null byte at the end of your word in the `hold[]` array.

```
 else
{
    /* j now refers to the array-slot which should be NULL */
    hold[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",hold);
    j = 0;
}
```